# Generate coverage report with stack

Tags: haskell, testing, code-coverage, haskell-stack

I want to generate code coverage report using Stack. I run command that
amounts to (omitting options passed to test suite via `--test-arguments`):

```
$ stack test --coverage
```

This performs the testing and then outputs the following:

> Error: The coverage report for myproject's test-suite "tests" did not
>   consider any code. One possible cause of this is if your test-suite builds
>   the library code (see stack issue #1008). It may also indicate a bug in
>   stack or the hpc program. Please report this issue if you think your
>   coverage report should have meaningful results.

I think it should (this creates empty report). GHC options are identical for
all components of my package. There is no need for test suite to rebuild the
library. After all, if Cabal can generate the report, Stack should be able
to do it given the same Cabal config or am I mistaken?

I've opened
[an issue on](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1224) Stack
GitHub repo as suggested.

---

After a while I decided to create good old sandbox and generate the report
using Cabal instead (I really need to see the report, you know). *It worked
previously, but now I get:*

```
$ cabal sandbox init
… <everything OK>
$ cabal update
… <everything OK>
$ cabal install --only-dependencies --enable-tests
… <everything OK>
$ cabal configure --enable-tests --enable-coverage
… <everything OK>
$ cabal build
… <everything OK>
$ cabal test
Running 2 test suites...
Test suite tests: RUNNING...
Test suite tests: PASS
Test suite logged to: dist/test/myproject-0.1.0-tests.log
hpc: can not find HUnit_DDLSMCRs3jyLBDbJPCH01j/Test.HUnit.Lang in ["./.hpc","./dist/hpc/vanilla/mix/myproject-0.1.0","./dist/hpc/vanilla/mix/tests"]
```

*What?* I've never seen this, although I generated many reports
before. Someone up there just decided that I won't get that report today,
it seems.

---

Do you know how to generate coverage report using Stack? Has anyone
succeeded at this?

Comment: What version of `stack` are you using? The latest version works better with `hpc`. I'm using `0.1.6.0` and it mostly works.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1181

Comment: @Yuras, `stack --version` → `Version 0.1.6.0, Git revision e22271f5ce9afa2cb5be3bad9cafa392c623f85c (2313 commits) x86_64`.

Comment: @Yuras, thanks for the link to that issue. I'm not the only one who get this! There should be some feedback on my issue too, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent changes upstream fixed it. Should be resolved for users of 0.1.7.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was still getting this error. Running:

```
stack clean
stack test --coverage
```

solved the problem, as reported [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1541).